# Understanding the creation of the __init__ method in instances

Tags: python, initialization, metaclass, monkeypatching

I am trying to understand the process of how objects are created in Python, namely the `__init__` method.
I need to understand these things to be able to write and debug code that leverages metaclasses.

Please consider the following code, that passes, and I don't understand why.

```
# define a class, with an __init__ method
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value


# instantiate regularly
a1 = A(1)
# or using the class's __call__
a2 = A.__call__(2)

assert a1.value == 1
assert a2.value == 2

# notice the instance of A has an __init__ method
assert hasattr(a1, "__init__")
# ... but no __call__ method [which makes sense]
assert not hasattr(a1, "__call__")
# A also has an __init__ method [which I thought would initialize A itself, and not its instances!]
assert hasattr(A, "__init__")

# I expected the instance's __init__ to be different than the class's __init__, which is the case.
A_init = A.__init__
init1 = a1.__init__
init2 = a2.__init__
assert init1 != init2
assert init1 != A_init
assert init2 != A_init


# However, the classes __init__ DOES NOT INITIALIZE THE CLASS! It initialized THE INSTANCE PROVIDED.
# The classes __init__ is not a bound method with its first argument `cls` as I expected. - What is it then?
# Does that mean the classes __init__ is actually a @classmethod?
init1(3)
init2(4)
assert a1.value == 3
assert a2.value == 4
A_init(a1, 5)  # This is a surprise 
assert a1.value == 5

# Let's try to invalidate the instance's __init__
# delattr(a1, "__init__") --> This doesn't remove the attribute - why?
a1.__init__ = lambda self, *args, **kwargs: None
a1.__init__(6)
# We see the instance's __init__ has changed successfully
assert a1.value == 5
# And the class's __init__ can still be used.
A.__init__(a1, 7)
assert a1.value == 7

# Let's now invalidate the class's init
A.__init__ = lambda self, *args, **kwargs: None
A.__init__(a2, 8)
assert a2.value == 4

# What's going on here? We never assigned into a2.__init__!
assert a2.__init__ != init2

# This makes sense, as init2 is bound to a2
init2(9)
assert a2.value == 9

# This doesn't make sense to me. It seems changing A's init somehow also changed the call to a2's
# but method resolution order can't explain that, because a2's __init__ should be called!
assert hasattr(A, "__init__")
assert hasattr(a2, "__init__")
a2.__init__(10)
assert a2.value == 9
```

I am having a hard time understanding the flow in which `__init__` is created and used, here are some things I don't understand from the above code:

1. When and how exactly is `__init__` created for instances and for classes
2. Which `__init__` gets called when
3. Why can't I use `delattr(a1, "**init**")?
4. Is the above true for any method? For any magic method? Is `__init__` some special case? Are there more special cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before all, `__init__` is a initializer. It's just a setup for an instance.
I think you are confusing `__new__` and `__init__`.

`__new__` is exactly what creates an instance. And then, `isnstance.__init__()` will be called.

### 1. When and how exactly is `__init__` created for instances and for classes

`__init__` for class will be created in same time class created.
But instance will never have it's own method. It's just a bound method. And every time called, bound method is created.

```python
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass


a = A()

print([id(m) for m in [a.__init__ for i in range(3)]])
# [2762836544256, 2762836475392, 2762836623680]
```

### 2. Which `__init__` gets called when

Right after instance have created, `instance.__init__()` will be called.

### 3. Why can't I use `delattr(a1, "init")`?

As I mentioned above, instance will never have it's own method. So, `a1` actually don't have `__init__` attribute. You can call delattr for the class.

```python
class A:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def some_func(self):
        print('yay')


a = A(4)
a.some_func()
delattr(A, 'some_func')
a.some_func()
"""
output:

yay
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\example.py", line 12, in <module>
    a.some_func()
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'some_func'
"""
```

### 4. Is the above true for any method? For any magic method? Is `__init__` some special case? Are there more special cases?

It's true for every methods.

Comment: Can you please share a link to the doc where I can read more about instances using bound methods? binding multiple times doesn't make sense to me, yet here you show it in 1.

Comment: Where can I look at the code that binds init to instances? I expect to see in the `__new__` of `object`: `self.__init__ = lambda self_, *args, **kwargs: cls.__init__(self_, *args, **kwargs)`. Still would like to actually read the nuances as well.

Comment: Also in 3. you say `__init__` is not an attribute. What is it then? What does happen when I do `a.__init__` if it doesn't go through `setattr`?

Comment: You can read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#methods). I think this and `The standard type hierarchy` which linked right above it will help you understand.